# radio button value is empty after <f:ajax> when i click on next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf

When I click next button on page 1 and go to page 2 and click previous button on page 2 to get to page 1 then I get radio button value as empty on page 1. I have no clue why ?!

I have this issue only with dynamic radio buttons i.e, if radio button is not at all selected than i face this issue!!Can some one help me in this! Thanks in advance !!

Below is my code:

```
<fieldset class="dol-selection-horizontal">
    <div class="cui-row">
        <div>
            <legend>
                <span id="severancePaymentsLabel">
                    Are you in hiring department?
                </span>
            </legend>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 135px;" align="right">
            <t:selectOneRadio id="severancePayments"
                              layout="spread" forceId="true" styleClass="required">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false"></f:selectItem>
            </t:selectOneRadio>
            <div class="dol-selection-wrapper">
                <t:radio for="severancePayments" index="0">
                </t:radio>
            </div>
            <div class="dol-selection-wrapper">
                <t:radio for="severancePayments" index="1">
                </t:radio>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="dol-selection-horizontal">
    <div class="cui-row">
        <div>
            <legend>
                <span id="lumpSumSeverancePaymentsLabel">
                    Core settings?
                </span>
            </legend>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 135px;" align="right">
            <div class="dol-selection-wrapper">
                <input id="lumpSumSeverancePayments_1" type="radio"
                       value="true" name="lumpSumSeverancePayments" class="required" />
                <label for="lumpSumSeverancePayments_1">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="dol-selection-wrapper">
                <input id="lumpSumSeverancePayments_2" type="radio"
                       value="false" name="lumpSumSeverancePayments" />
                <label for="lumpSumSeverancePayments_2">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<div id="lumpSumSeverancePaymentsYes" style="display:  none;">
    <div class="cui-row">
        <label for="totalGrossAmount">
            Are options available?
        </label>
        <h:inputText id="totalGrossAmount"
                     name="totalGrossAmount" type="text" styleClass="required" />
    </div>

    <fieldset class="dol-selection-horizontal">
        <div class="cui-row">
            <div>
                <legend>
                    <span id="receiveFirstLumpSumLabel">
                        Did you read the entire contract?
                    </span>
                </legend>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 135px;" align="right">
                <t:selectOneRadio id="receiveFirstLumpSum"
                                  layout="spread" forceId="true" styleClass="required">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true">
                    </f:selectItem>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false">
                    </f:selectItem>
                </t:selectOneRadio>
                <div class="dol-selection-wrapper">
                    <t:radio for="receiveFirstLumpSum" index="0">
                    </t:radio>
                </div>
                <div class="dol-selection-wrapper">
                    <t:radio for="receiveFirstLumpSum" index="1">
                    </t:radio>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div id="receiveFirstLumpSumYes" style="display:  none;">
        <div class="cui-row">
            <label for="firstLumpSumDate">
                Marketing Date?
            </label>
            <h:inputText id="firstLumpSumDate"
                         name="firstLumpSumDate" type="text" styleClass="required dateMask" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbtnu.jpg
```

I have ajax calls to go to next and previous page:

```
    <f:ajax execute="wageQuestionnairePageOneFormDiv" onevent="function(data) { 
    ajaxEventGoToNextPage(data, 'PageOneForm', 'PageTwoForm' ) }" 
    render="messagesDiv" onerror="ajaxOnError"></f:ajax>



    <f:ajax execute="@none" onevent="function(data) { 
    ajaxEventGoToPrevPage(data, 'PageTwoForm', 'PageOneForm') }" 
    render="messagesDiv" onerror="ajaxOnError"></f:ajax>
```

Comment: i can't see where do you store the selected value in selectOneRadio elements.

Comment: I don't want to store any value back.

Comment: you don't want it but JSF need the values stored in managed beans to restore the views.